# Command AT and CUSD result

Tags: asterisk, ussd

I send USSD command with AT.
Sometimes I receive the response CUSD=4 sometimes it works for the same input.
The error always appends at the beginning of a new USSD session (#xxx#).

Do you know what exactly means this response? The description of the error is operation not supported.
Is-this message due to the modem or to the network?
How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such message mean you(or soft) issues AT+CUSD command

Any response except 0,1 are errors.

Exact error have follow message. Try enable debug to see full message.

Code 4 can mean different things depend of modem used, for more info you need check AT commands for modem you have.